# kernel panics possibly related to XNU and CUDA

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

I'm running a CUDA program on my Late 2013 model MBP running OS X 10.10.5, the GPU is NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB. Unexpectedly and in a non-reproducible fashion it is giving kernel panics. The kernel panics are like the following. The program that is running is a software I've developed.

I've updated CUDA and OS X. It seems to be failing in some XNU and related to the graphics driver.

Is there something I can do to troubleshoot this?

```
Anonymous UUID:       0AF8CBEF-52D8-B060-0804-C6C8A204DC99

Sun Sep 13 12:07:20 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff7f9dc5fc14): "OSObject::_RESERVEDOSObject3 called."@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.40.9/libkern/c++/OSMetaClass.cpp:1067
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff821d902e50 : 0xffffff801bd2ad21 
0xffffff821d902ed0 : 0xffffff7f9dc5fc14 
0xffffff821d902f20 : 0xffffff7f9dbdf886 
0xffffff821d902f60 : 0xffffff7f9dbf8b68 
0xffffff821d902fa0 : 0xffffff7f9dc9f2ea 
0xffffff821d9036c0 : 0xffffff7f9dca4a08 
0xffffff821d9037c0 : 0xffffff7f9dbf7368 
0xffffff821d903830 : 0xffffff7f9dbf6fac 
0xffffff821d903850 : 0xffffff7f9dbf89bb 
0xffffff821d903870 : 0xffffff7f9dca3928 
0xffffff821d903890 : 0xffffff7f9dbf8aa4 
0xffffff821d9038b0 : 0xffffff7f9dca3928 
0xffffff821d9038d0 : 0xffffff7f9dc018c1 
0xffffff821d903910 : 0xffffff7f9dc02817 
0xffffff821d903a10 : 0xffffff7f9dc01ad7 
0xffffff821d903a50 : 0xffffff7f9dbff84e 
0xffffff821d903ad0 : 0xffffff801c2ff3cc 
0xffffff821d903b60 : 0xffffff801c301523 
0xffffff821d903bc0 : 0xffffff801c2fed83 
0xffffff821d903d00 : 0xffffff801bde1307 
0xffffff821d903e10 : 0xffffff801bd2ef8c 
0xffffff821d903e40 : 0xffffff801bd139f3 
0xffffff821d903e90 : 0xffffff801bd2429d 
0xffffff821d903f10 : 0xffffff801be0231a 
0xffffff821d903fb0 : 0xffffff801be344c6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.16)[1259B80F-E4C5-3BC9-BED5-65B42289E8C0]@0xffffff7f9dbde000->0xffffff7f9dc4cfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f9c524000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f9c7ec000
         com.apple.GeForce(10.0.4)[FC98B4E2-5F4F-3C64-B3C0-F3D02E1C5813]@0xffffff7f9dc5b000->0xffffff7f9dcf1fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f9c524000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f9c833000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0.4)[95736EED-9154-3CBF-B639-6038E7128035]@0xffffff7f9c84a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f9c7ec000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.16)[1259B80F-E4C5-3BC9-BED5-65B42289E8C0]@0xffffff7f9dbde000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
Kernel slide:     0x000000001ba00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801bc00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801bb00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,3 (Mac-2BD1B31983FE1663)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 40358926503470
last loaded kext at 374641777549: com.nvidia.CUDA   1.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9e893000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 374362740076: com.nvidia.CUDA 1.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9e893000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
com.nvidia.CUDA 1.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.10
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.10
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.10
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.36.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.25
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.4
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.25
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.16
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
```

Comment: does it only happen when you program is executed?

Comment: @bMalum: Unfortunately, yes. Sometimes after running for 15 minutes, sometimes after running for 4 hours.